# ISC DHCP fails to sync leases between peers

Tags: linux, load-balancing, dhcp, failover

I use ISC DHCP version 4.1.1 on Debian GNU/Linux on both servers.
I tried to solve the following problem using various versions of ISC DHCP but it remained the same.

My configuration for failover between two servers on different subnets is:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
# Primary Server
#-----------------------------------------------

authoritative;
default-lease-time 900;
max-lease-time 1800;         
option domain-name "foo.com";
option domain-name-servers 10.12.0.254;

failover peer "foo" {
    primary;
    address 10.12.0.254;
    port 647;
    peer address 10.10.10.12;
    peer port 647;
    max-response-delay 30;
    max-unacked-updates 10;
    load balance max seconds 3;
    mclt 1800;  
    split 128;
}

subnet 10.12.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
    pool {
        failover peer "foo";
        range 10.12.10.0 10.12.112.0;
        range 10.12.112.12 10.12.255.254;
        deny dynamic bootp clients;
    }
    option routers 10.12.0.254;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.12.255.255;
}

#-----------------------------------------------
# Secondary Server
#-----------------------------------------------

authoritative;
default-lease-time 900;
max-lease-time 1800;
option domain-name "foo.com";
option domain-name-servers 10.12.0.254;

failover peer "foo" {
        secondary;
        address 10.10.10.12;
        port 647;
        peer address 10.12.0.254;
        peer port 647;
        max-response-delay 30;
        max-unacked-updates 10;
        load balance max seconds 3;
}

subnet 10.12.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
        pool {
                failover peer "foo";
                range 10.12.10.0 10.12.112.0;
                range 10.12.112.12 10.12.255.254;
        deny dynamic bootp clients;
        }
    option routers 10.12.0.254;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.12.255.255;
}

subnet 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
}
```

IP helper (aka UDP helper) and DHCP relay is enabled on router that connects the network of the primary server with the network of the secondary server
I can ping and ssh from one server to the other and back.

When I start the dhcpd service on both servers they fail to balance their leases.

I paste a sample of the logs of both servers

Primary Server

```
Sep 19 10:31:11 primary dhcpd: failover peer foo: I move from recover to startup
Sep 19 10:31:11 primary dhcpd: failover peer foo: I move from startup to recover
Sep 19 10:31:11 primary dhcpd: Sent update request all message to foo
Sep 19 10:31:20 primary dhcpd: peer foo: disconnected
Sep 19 10:31:22 primary dhcpd: failover peer foo: peer moves from recover-done to recover-done
Sep 19 10:31:22 primary dhcpd: failover peer foo: peer moves from recover-done to recover-done
Sep 19 10:31:45 primary dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.12.181.177 via eth1
Sep 19 10:31:45 primary dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.12.181.177 (00:17:42:c0:e3:ce) via eth1
Sep 19 10:32:45 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c (PC1) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:32:46 primary dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.12.181.177 via eth1
Sep 19 10:32:46 primary dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.12.181.177 (00:17:42:c0:e3:ce) via eth1
Sep 19 10:32:49 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c (PC1) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:32:57 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c (PC1) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:33:13 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 (PC2) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:33:13 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c (PC1) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:33:17 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 (PC2) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:33:25 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 (PC2) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
Sep 19 10:33:41 primary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 (PC2) via eth1: not responding (recovering)
```

Secondary Server

```
Sep 19 10:31:11 secondary dhcpd: Update request all from foo: sending update
Sep 19 10:31:23 secondary dhcpd: Wrote 22 leases to leases file.
Sep 19 10:31:23 secondary dhcpd: failover peer foo: I move from recover-done to startup
Sep 19 10:31:23 secondary dhcpd: failover peer foo: I move from startup to recover-done
Sep 19 10:31:45 secondary dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.12.181.177 via 10.12.0.1
Sep 19 10:31:45 secondary dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.12.181.177 (00:17:42:c0:e3:ce) via eth0
Sep 19 10:32:45 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:32:46 secondary dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 10.12.181.177 via 10.12.0.1
Sep 19 10:32:46 secondary dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.12.181.177 (00:17:42:c0:e3:ce) via eth0
Sep 19 10:32:49 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:32:57 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:33:13 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:33:13 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:33:17 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:33:25 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:33:41 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:19:99:95:41:99 via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:34:46 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1a:4b:45:3a:2f via 10.12.0.1: peer holds all free leases
Sep 19 10:34:51 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1a:4b:45:3a:2f via 10.12.0.1: peer holds all free leases
Sep 19 10:34:59 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1a:4b:45:3a:2f via 10.12.0.1: peer holds all free leases
Sep 19 10:35:16 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1a:4b:45:3a:2f via 10.12.0.1: peer holds all free leases
Sep 19 10:38:28 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
Sep 19 10:38:32 secondary dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:16:d3:e5:3a:3c via 10.12.0.1: not responding (recover done)
```

I don't seem to have the load balance log lines so I don't think leases balancing is happening...

```
Sent update request all message to foo
Update request all from foo: sending update
```

Balancing process seems stuck on the two lines above

If I shut down the DHCPD daemon on one server the peer doesn't seem to take over even if it detects that other peer is down

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance (and sorry for my bad English) :-)

Comment: This bug report belongs to dhcpd's mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `not responding (recovering)` indicates that the server is not responding because it is recovering from a failover (or initial start). And is probably still populating the lease databases with all of the free leases from your pool, which could take a while if you have a large pool.

Try with a smaller pool to verify your failover is working correctly, then readjust. Your range is very large and likely the cause of why it seems to hang on update.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into this issue before.  For me it was the firewall blocking port 647/tcp on both servers.  I ran the following on each server and it resolved the issue.

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=647/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Afterwards, restart the dhcpd service.

Comment: This caused some headaches for me where my primary dhcpd server was stuck in `(recover wait)`. I guess in the past I had failed to add the --permanent flag.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `peer holds all free leases` can also mean that the request has been received on the wrong network interface, e.g. if a computer is only configured to get an IP on `eth0`, but the DHCP request is received on `eth1`. `deny dynamic bootp clients` is typical for such a setup. In my case one interface was for the workstation network and the other one for printers only and someone plugged a workstation into the printer network.

See [my blog posting about when I ran into that error message and found no obvious reason](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/peer%20holds%20all%20free%20leases.futile) on Debian, too.

I can't remember having seen the message `not responding (recovering)` back then, but I also had `peer holds all free leases` on both DHCP servers.